# How to extract nested data by iMacros

Tags: imacros

I am using iMacros under chrome.
I have:

```
<div class="BigClass">
    <span>AAA</span>
        <br class="clear">
            <span>BBB</span>
</div>
```

I used:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:BigClass EXTRACT=TXT
```

I get:

```
AAA        BBB
```

What I want is:

```
AAA
```

How to select `AAA` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:BigClass EXTRACT=HTM
SET nestedData EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/<span>(\w*)<\/span>/)[1];")
```